# InfiniteViewPager setCurrentItem not displaying the fragment contents

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm currently using the [antonyt](https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager) infiniteViewPager to make my viewPager looks like an endless scroll. It works just fine on my end and I also applied some changes since I need to change the current item depending on what I click from my navigation drawer. Now to handle that I just created a shared preference to handle the position and virtual position of the pages by changing the InfinitePagerAdapter and adding this lines in getPageTitle method (since I also have a title strip):

```
SharedPreferences tab_pages = context.getSharedPreferences("pages", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
tab_pages.edit().putInt(String.valueOf(position % getRealCount()), position).commit();
```

Now from here it works and changes the current page but doesn't display the fragment contents that should be a listview with some images. Here's the code on changing tabs:

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        SharedPreferences tab_pages = getSharedPreferences("pages", MODE_PRIVATE);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_pages.getInt("0", 0), false);
                break;
            case 1:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_pages.getInt("1", 0), false);
                break;
            case 2:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_pages.getInt("2", 0), false);
                break;
            case 3:
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_pages.getInt("3", 0), false);
                break;
        }
    }
```

What happens is that it only change my title strip correctly but doesn't display the fragment content. It does display correctly sometimes but most of the time only for the position 0 and not for the other positions and I think the infiniteViewPager has the major role on why does this happen though I'm not really sure what is the exact reason. Also if I tried to spam change the page using the navigation drawer it stops and gives me a null pointer exception. logs below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.test.kahel(MainActivity.java:168)
            at com.test.kahel.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:241)
            at com.test.kahel.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:89)
```

Comment: Your logic can be optimized by removing the switch and using `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab_pages.getInt(position+"", 0), false);` instead.

Comment: Also check if mViewPager is not null on onCreate. Because you're calling `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` on onCreate (line 89) and I think that your view is not created yet.